# Where does India fall in Peter Theil's matrix?

Tags: macroeconomics

In his  book "Zero to one"  Peter Theil describes a 2 X 2 matrix on how societies think about future.  Definite optimism (e.g. 1950s US), Definite Pessimism (Present day China), Indefinite Pessimism (Present Day Europe) and finally Indefinite Optimism (Present day US).  Does present day India fit in to one of these categories?

[image: Peter Theil]

Comment: Welcome to Econ.SE! What is your guess and why?

Comment: My guess would be Indefinite Pessimism. Because all the economic reforms until recently  in India were forced on it compared to a well planned approach by China. But I am a little confused due to the factors like high GDP growth rate and high national savings rate.